# I have to make a dfa over the alphabet Σ = { 0, 1, 2 } of strings that end with the same digit twice; e.g., strings that end in 00, 11, 22

Tags: dfa

hi can you please go over my dfa for this and tell me if its correct??[image]

Answer (score 1):

this forum is meant for research level questions. Your question seems to be an exercise to a first course on formal languages and would fit more in the following forum https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Concerning your automata, it is not correct as it refuses e.g. 122.

Answer (score 0):

dfa over the alphabet Σ = { 0, 1, 2 } of strings that end with the same digit twice; e.g., strings that end in 00, 11, 22
Transition diagram for the corresponding language[image]

Comment: This looks more like an homework assignment in an undergraduate course than a research question?